# C++ Creating Array of Pointers to Nodes in Directed Graph

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a directed graph represented by an array of pointers to nodes, but I'm struggling to add nodes into each index of the graph. Here is what I have:

```
struct Node {
    int index;                 
    list<Node*> outgoingNodes; 
};

struct Graph {
    Node* nodePointers; // Array of pointers to nodes in graph
    int N;              // Number of nodes in graph       
};
```

Here is how I am creating the graph:

```
Graph* graph = new Graph();
graph->N = 7;
graph->nodePointers = new Node[graph->N];
```

I then try to add a node into index 0 in the graph in the following way, but I get an error that "operand types are 'Node' and 'Node*'":

```
Node* a = new Node();
a->index = 0;
graph->nodePointers[0] = a;
```

Without changing either of my structs, how could I correctly add a node into an index in my graph's array of node pointers?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `Graph* graph = new Graph();` -- Why not simply `Graph graph;`?

Comment: That would work just as well, but it doesn't look like that solves the issue of adding a node into an index in the graph's array of pointers

Comment: *issue of adding a node* --  Your attempt is not adding a `Node` -- it is attempting to add a `Node *`, and that is wrong.  So before an answer, what are you trying to accomplish?  Is it to utilize an array of `Node *`, or an array of `Node`?  If it's the former, your declaration in `Graph` is wrong.  If it's the latter, then add a `Node` and not `Node *`.

Comment: I'm hoping to utilize an array of Node*, though correcting my declaration of graph to "Graph graph" doesn't seem to solve the issue. Is there a way to utilize an array of Node* while keeping my declaration of graph as a pointer to graph?

Comment: My point of `Graph graph;` is to emphasize the need to *not* allocate memory.  C++ is not Java or other languages where every object needs to be created with `new`.

Answer (score 2):

`Node* nodePointers` is a pointer to an array of `Node`s. If you want an array of `Node` pointers, you need to declare it as `Node** nodePointers`, and allocate the array with `new Node*[graph->N]`:

```
struct Graph {
    Node** nodePointers; // Array of pointers to nodes in graph
    int N;              // Number of nodes in graph       
};

int main() {
    Graph* graph = new Graph();
    graph->N = 7;
    graph->nodePointers = new Node*[graph->N];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
struct Node {
    int index;                 
    list<Node*> outgoingNodes; 
};
```

Although correct, it is inefficient for no apparent reason. Almost always prefer a vector over a list. It is as easy to work with, but takes less memory and works faster on almost any conceivable use case:

```
struct Node {
    int index;                 
    std::vector<Node*> outgoingNodes; 
};
```

Next, the code:

```
struct Graph {
    Node* nodePointers; // Array of pointers to nodes in graph
    int N;              // Number of nodes in graph       
};
```

Holds a block of Node objects, not pointers to nodes. The best thing is to use a vector of pointers:

```
struct Graph {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> nodePointers; // pointers to nodes in graph

};
```

This way deallocation and memory management will be automatic.

Then your usage example becomes:

```
// are you sure graph has to be on the heap?
auto graph = std:: make_unique<Graph>();
graph->nodePointers.resize(7);
```

I then you can add a node into index 0 in the graph in the following way:

```
graph->nodePointers[0] = std::make_unique<Node>();
graph->nodePointers[0]->index = 0;
```

---

This was the better way to do it, but if you insist on:

> Without changing either of my structs, how could I correctly add a
>   node into an index in my graph's array of node pointers?

Then you should note that "graph's array" is not made of pointers, but of nodes. So adding nodes is done differently:

```
// you can still allocate the graph on the heap, but the following way is safer
Graph graph;
graph.N = 7;
graph.nodePointers = new Node[graph.N];
```

But now nodePointers is a misnomer, because it should be named nodes (not pointers).

Then  add a node into index 0 in the graph in the following way (by this point it is already constructed):

```
graph->nodePointers[0].index = 0;
```

And adding an edge looks lije:

```
graph->nodePointers[0].outgoingNodes.push_back(&graph->nodePointets[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

At line `graph->nodePointers[0] = a;` change this to `graph->nodePointers[0] = *a;` It will work.

Now let me explain you, Suppose you want an array of int then you can declare it as `int x[10] or int *x=new int(10)`. What it shows in second case that x is an pointer which points to int object not to int pointer. I hope you got your solution.